# socket.timeout timed out when connecting to a remote server with web3.py

Tags: web3js, parity, python, web3-providers

I use Web3 to connect to my remote server.

`10.xxx.xxx.xxx`is ip address of a remote server.

First I start the server with this command :
`parity --chain frontier.json --rpcapi="eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpc --rpcaddr 10.xxx.xxx.xxx --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --author 0x...`

And after I run a python script :

`from web3 import Web3, KeepAliveRPCProvider
web3 = Web3(KeepAliveRPCProvider(host="163.xxx.xxx.xxx", port="8545"))
web3.eth.coinbase`

But I've this error : `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

If I remplace host by `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` I've `socket.timeout: timed out` error

Moreover, if I install python and web3 on the remote server and run this command :

`from web3 import Web3, KeepAliveRPCProvider
web3 = Web3(KeepAliveRPCProvider(host="10.xxx.xxx.xxx", port="8545"))
web3.eth.syncing`
I don't have any error

But if I run this command on an other server I've the same error : `socket.timeout: timed out`

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

First double check that IP addresses are correct in your scripts.

Then use telnet command to ensure that you can connect to RPC port from the client computer:

```
 telnet 163.xxx.xxx.xxx 8545
```

You should see raw HTTP output and it should give you a hint of what could be wrong.

If this doesn't connect then fix whatever network/firewall/etc. issues you have between the computers.

Comment: Yes in fact, wwhen I do `telnet 163.172.151.230 8545` I can see that I 'm connect.

Comment: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` usually indicates that the server running in the destination is returning HTML payload. Are you sure you are connected to correct geth? You can also try to peek into raw network traffic and HTTP response what geth is returning.

Comment: How can I check if I'm connect to the correct geth? I run parity with the command write into my post. I don't know if it's a problem but I jsut can run this command with `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` witch is the private ip address. With the `162.172.151.230`witch is the public ip this command give me an error.

Comment: Sorry I was meaning parity.

Comment: Try send a JSON-RPC directly from the command line using `curl`. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#web3_clientversion

Comment: When I tried to do ` curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://163.172.151.230:8545`I've this response : `Provided Host header is not whitelisted.`. What doest it means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51926/discussion-between-wxcvbn-and-mikko-ohtamaa).